# Error: Missing closing quote on parameter "Name"

Tags: inno-setup

At compile time, Inno keeps saying there was an error:

```
Line: 81
Error: Missing closing quote on parameter "Name"
```

but I don't see anything wrong.  It points to the line just below [icons]

```
[Files]
Source: "{#SOURCEDIR}\Debug\myapplication.exe"; DestDir: {app}; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "{#SOURCEDIR}\Debug\aDllFile.dll"; DestDir: {app}; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "{#SOURCEDIR}\Debug\another.aDllFile.dll"; DestDir: {app}; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "{#SOURCEDIR}\Debug\and.another.aDllFile.dll"; DestDir: {app}; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#APPTITLE}"; Filename: "{app}\{#APPEXENAME}"
Name: "{group}\{cm:ProgramOnTheWeb,{#APPTITLE}}"; Filename: "{#APPURL}"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#APPTITLE}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#APPTITLE}"; Filename: "{app}\{#APPEXENAME}"; Tasks: desktopicon
Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\{#APPTITLE}"; Filename: "{app}\{#APPEXENAME}"; Tasks: quicklaunchicon
Name: "{userstartup}\{#APPTITLE}"; Filename: "{app}\{#APPEXENAME}"; IconFilename: "{app}\{#APPEXENAME}"; 

[Run]
;Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, ""&"", ""&&"")}}"; Flags: nowait RunHidden SkipIfDoesntExist; Parameters: exit; WorkingDir: {app}; 
Filename: {app}\{#APPEXENAME}; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(APPNAME, "noupdate", "&&")}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent


[Messages]
WelcomeLabel1=Welcome to the Setup Wizard for%n[name]
WelcomeLabel2=Salve!  This application will install [name/ver] on your computer.  You do not need administrator rights to do this.%n%nIf you would close your other applications before continuing, it would be mighty nice of you.
ExitSetupMessage=Hey!  I'm not finished installing!%n  If you exit now, the program will not be installed.%n%nHowever, you can always run the Setup again some other time if you wish to complete the installation.%n%nDo you still want to exit?
InfoBeforeLabel=Just a few little notes about {#APPTITLE}...
InfoBeforeClickLabel=When you are ready to continue the Installation, just click Next.
SelectTasksDesc=Just a few little tidbits, if you like them...
```

*[note]*

I can't believe this question was viewed 1003 times and noone gave me a vote!

Comment: Which is line 81 and what are SOURCEDIR and APPTITLE (and any others) defined as?

Comment: Do any of your macros  - {#APPTITLE}, etc. - contain a quote? Also try and delete the comment line just above [Icons], just shooting at random, but it has quotes in it.

Comment: BGM has already found out why it's occuring (Quote in a file description and in turn, in an ISPP define) and posted in another forum. I've asked them to reply here too.

Comment: @Deanna Sorry- I had to go to bed; y'all posted here before I could add the comment!  I didn't have enough reputation points to post it last night when I found it; anyway, I am also posting the reply I received from Inno staff.

Comment: You say in your answer that the problem was in defined macro, but where is it shown in your question ? The question itself doesn't contain all the code needed to resolve the problem and as such could have been even put on hold as off-topic for reason: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."* So don't be surprised you didn't get an upvote ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.  One of my definitions was failing.  It was supposed to extract the file_description from the target executable's resource.

```
#define APPTITLE GetStringFileInfo("C:\sourcepath\myapplication.exe", FILE_DESCRIPTION)
```

There was a ' in the File Description!  And that caused Inno to offest all of its quotation marks.

Here is what Dee Earley at the Inno forum told me:

*Why should it escape it? It doesn't know what it needs to escape it for, it's "just a string". You should escape it for it's output when needed using StringChange() or just quoting it properly. '*